# substr() from the 1. to the last character C++

Tags: c++, string, substr

I would like to use substr() function in order to get the chain of characters from the 1. to the last, without 0.
Should I do sth like this:
`string str = xyz.substr(1, xyz.length());`
or `(xyz.length() - 1)` ? And why?

Comment: I will do `xyz.substr(1)`

Answer (score 24):

You don't  need to specify the number of character to include. So as I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698270/substr-from-the-1-to-the-last-character-c/34698360#comment57142757_34698270):

```
string str = xyz.substr(1)
```

This will return all characters until the end of the string

Answer (score 9):

The signature for substr is

```
string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;
```

As the length of the new string is 1 less than the old string you should call it as follows:

```
string str = xyz.substr(1, xyz.length() - 1);
```

You can actually omit the second argument as it defaults to string::npos. "A value of string::npos indicates all characters until the end of the string." (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

Comment: `xyz.substr(1)` is much better.

Answer (score 4):

The both declarations

```
std::string str = xyz.substr( 1, xyz.length() );
```

and

```
std::string str = xyz.substr( 1, xyz.length() - 1 );
```

are valid (though the first one can confuse the reader of the code) provided  that the size of `str` is not equal to 0.

However this declaration

```
std::string str = xyz.substr( 1 );
```

is more expressive.

If string `xyz` can be an empty string then you should write something like

```
std::string str = xyz.substr( !xyz.empty() ? 1 : 0 );
```

or

```
std::string str = xyz.substr( xyz.size() != 0 ? 1 : 0 );
```

Comment: @user3100115 They all need to determine the length, but it's stored not computed so not really an issue. (`string::size()` is required to be O(1).)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the sub string of string starting from a certain index till the end of the string, you can do the following.

```
char * substring(char *s){
    return s;
 }

 int main(){
char s[1][n]; // suppose we just take a single string.
char *sub;

scanf("%s",s[1]);            //s[1]="ababaaa"

sub=substring(s[1]+1);      //sub="babaaa"(starting from 1st index).
sub=substring(s[1]+3);      //sub="baaa" (starting from 3rd index).

return 0;
}
```